# Cast button not available in YTPlayerView

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, ytplayerview

cast button not available in YTPlayerView for iOS, which has only play, pause, seek, and so.

How to get cast button in YTPlayerview?

Comment: cast button is not embed in ytplayerview, if we need then customize based on the need

Comment: Thanks karthik. I would like to cast a youtube video from my app. So, you mentioned that we have to do that casting and youtube doesn't provide the casting feature?